# Unable to run JUnit test cases after converting project to Gradle in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, gradle

I was using Maven to manage my project in Eclipse, but decided that Gradle looked like something that could end up benefiting me more. I'm trying to implement a CI/CD pipeline, but want to check certain thing (unit test success, and code coverage for example). After converting my project using

```
gradle eclipse
```

I find that I am no longer able to run JUnit test cases via the context menu

```
Right Click -> Run As... -> JUnit Test
```

With the following error

```
Class not found <package>.<class>
```

But when I run

```
gradle test
```

All of them pass, but don't give me any more information (which were run, which ones failed, which ones errored out).

By switching to a Gradle project, can all tasks only be run in the context of Gradle now? There are no errors reported in Eclipse, and building works fine. I have verified that the files are in the expected locations.

Comment: No, it is assumed that you will be able to run your tests in Eclipse. Take a look at [userguide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html) and get back to your question. You can resolve the problem or possibly refine your question with more detailed description so that other people can help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to solve this doing the following steps.

1. Close the project in eclipse
2. Delete the project from the eclipse workspace (not from the file system)
3. Close eclipse
4. Open command line terminal
5. Run `gradle cleanEclipse eclipse`
6. Open eclipse
7. Import as a gradle project

At that point, everything was set up again.

Answer (score 2):

This was happening to me as well.  I was comparing Gradle to Maven, and I couldn't right mouse click on my Test.java file and Run as JUnit Test.  My project had originally started as a Maven project, and I had converted it to Gradle.  The problem was due to the old JUnit Run Configurations.  All I did was go into Run Configurations and delete all the ones for JUnit.  After I did this it started working.  Hope this helps as the gradle eclipseClean eclipse didn't work for me.

Comment: Fellow reviewers: it is _not_ a new question. He's telling what worked for him when he had the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

You could have done just with single step "Import as a gradle project" in newer Eclipse IDE instance.

Comment: I did the first time. It didn't get initialized correctly, so that's why I had to do that.