# Test failed in Gradle but working fine in Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

test are running successfully with the maven and failing with Gradle

I have a strange issue my spring boot application (version 2.1.0), which is using JPA(spring-boot-starter-data-jpa) for integrating with mysql db, there are integration test cases that i have defined using TestRest Template , but this are running successfully with the maven(3.5.4) test command and failing with Gradle(4.6),  We have tried to have the same configuration for both the pom.xml and build.gradle

```
pom.xml   
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.eudsys.spring.integ</groupId>
    <artifactId>integration</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>integration</name>
    <description>Eudsys project for Spring Integration</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>auth0-spring-security-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0.905</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>0.8.1</version>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </execution>
                  <execution>
                    <id>default-report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </execution>
                  <execution>
                      <id>default-jacoco-check</id>
                      <goals>
                          <goal>check</goal>
                      </goals>
                      <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <rule>
                                <element>PACKAGE</element>
                                <limits>
                                    <limit>
                                        <counter>LINE</counter>
                                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                        <minimum>0.5</minimum>
                                    </limit>
                                </limits>
                            </rule>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
 </project>



 build.gradle

    buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.0.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.5"
  }
}
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
    id 'org.gretty' version '2.2.0'

}
plugins {
  id "org.sonarqube" version "2.5"
}
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war' 
apply plugin: 'org.gretty' 
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
bootJar {
    baseName = 'gs-spring-boot'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0' 
    runtime 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.1.2'

    compile group: 'com.sun.mail', name: 'javax.mail', version:'1.5.5'
    compile group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version:'1.18.2'
    compile group: 'net.bytebuddy', name: 'byte-buddy', version: '1.8.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.9.5'

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core')
    compile('javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0')
    compile("com.auth0:java-jwt:3.4.0")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
     compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    runtime(group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version:'8.0.13') {
        exclude(module: 'protobuf-java')
    }
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.1"
    reportsDir = file("$buildDir/customJacocoReportDir")
}

test {
    jacoco {
        append = false
        destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/jacocoTest.exec")
        classDumpDir = file("$buildDir/jacoco/classpathdumps")
    }
    testLogging {
        showStandardStreams = true
    }
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination file("${buildDir}/jacocoHtml")
    }
}

jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
    violationRules {
        rule {
            limit {
                minimum = 0.2
            }
        }

        rule {
            enabled = false
            element = 'CLASS'
            includes = ['org.gradle.*']

            limit {
                counter = 'LINE'
                value = 'TOTALCOUNT'
                maximum = 0.3
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Failed TestController in gradle but working fine in maven

```
        package com.eudsys.spring;

        import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.util.Collection;
        import java.util.List;

        import org.junit.AfterClass;
        import org.junit.Assert;
        import org.junit.Before;
        import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;
        import org.junit.Test;
        import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
        import org.junit.runners.MethodSorters;
        import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
        import org.mockito.Mock;
        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
        import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
        import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment;
        import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
        import org.springframework.data.web.config.EnableSpringDataWebSupport;
        import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
        import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
        import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
        import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
        import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
        import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
        import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
        import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;

        import com.eudsys.spring.db.Account;
        import com.eudsys.spring.db.ApplicationUser;
        import com.eudsys.spring.db.Branch;
        import com.eudsys.spring.db.Company;
        import com.eudsys.spring.db.SecurityQuestion;
        import com.eudsys.spring.db.UserBranch;
        import com.eudsys.spring.db.UserQuestion;
        import com.eudsys.spring.db.UsersDetail;
        import com.eudsys.spring.util.RandomString;
        import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
        import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
        import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

        @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
        @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
        @EnableSpringDataWebSupport
        @FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
        public class UserManagementUpdateTest {

            private static RandomString randomString = new RandomString(10);
            private static String RANDOM_EMAIL = randomString.nextString() + "@yopmail.com";
            private static String RANDOM_INVITE_EMAIL = randomString.nextString() + "@yopmail.com";
            private static String RANDOM_COMP_NAME = "Partho_" + randomString.nextString();
            private static String RANDOM_COMP_LICENC = randomString.nextString();
            private static Long RANDOM_COMP_DUNS_NUM = (randomString.generateNumber() / 1000);
            private static Long RANDOM_PHONE = randomString.generateNumber();
            private static Long RANDOM_INVITE_PHONE = randomString.generateNumber();
            private static String CORP_TYPE = "CORP";
            private static String REGISTER_REQUEST = null;
            private static String UPDATE_CORP_REQUEST = null;
            private static String FORGET_LOGIN_REQUEST = null;
            private static String FORGET_EMAIL_REQUEST = null;
            private static String RESET_PASSWD_REQUEST = null;
            private static String LOGIN_REQUEST = null;
            private static String NEW_BRANCH_REQUEST = null;
            private static String INVITE_REQUEST = null;
            private static String COMPANY_EDIT_REQUEST = null;
            private static String EMAIL_TOKEN = "EMAILTOKEN";
            private static String EMAIL_INVITE_TOKEN = "EMAILTOKEN";
            private static String AUTH_TOKEN = "AUTHTOKEN";
            private static String TESTLOGIN = "test" + randomString.nextString();
            private static String TESTINVITELOGIN = "test" + randomString.nextString();
            private static String TESTANSWER = "testanswer";
            private static int TESTQUESTION = 1;
            private static int TESTACCOUNT = 1;
            private static ApplicationUser userfound = new ApplicationUser();
            private static Account accountFound = new Account();
            private static ApplicationUser inviteUserfound = new ApplicationUser();
            private static Account inviteAccountFound = new Account();
            private static UserQuestion question = new UserQuestion();
            private static Branch branchCreated=new Branch();
            private static SecurityQuestion securityquestion = new SecurityQuestion();

            MockMvc mockMvc;



            @Autowired
            IntegrationApplication integrationApplication;
            @Autowired
            private TestRestTemplate template;

            @Mock
            private static UserManagementController userManagementController;

            @InjectMocks
            @Autowired
            private UserManagementUpdateController userManagementUpdateController;

            @Before
            public void setup() throws Exception {
                try {
                    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(userManagementController, userManagementUpdateController).build();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Test
            public void test1AllUsers() throws Exception {
                ResponseEntity<List> response = template.getForEntity("/employees", List.class);
                System.out.println(response.getStatusCode().value());
                Assert.assertEquals(200, response.getStatusCode().value());
                response = template.getForEntity("/employees", List.class);
                System.out.println(response.getStatusCode().value());
                Assert.assertEquals(200, response.getStatusCode().value());
            }

            @Test
            public void test2BRegisterUser() throws Exception {

                REGISTER_REQUEST = "{\"loginid\":\"" + TESTLOGIN + "\",\"email\":\"" + RANDOM_EMAIL + "\"," + "\"type\":\""
                        + CORP_TYPE + "\"}";
                HttpEntity<Object> applicationUser = postHttpEntity(REGISTER_REQUEST);
                ResponseEntity<ApplicationUser> response = template.postForEntity("/register", applicationUser,
                        ApplicationUser.class);

                Assert.assertEquals(200, response.getStatusCode().value());
                if (response.getBody() != null) {
                    userfound = response.getBody();
                    EMAIL_TOKEN = userfound.getEmail_token();
                    TESTACCOUNT = userfound.getAccount().getId();
                    System.out.println(" User Found : " + userfound);
                    // userRepository.

                }

            }


            @Test
            public void test4DCanLogin() throws Exception {
                LOGIN_REQUEST = "{\"login\":\"" + TESTLOGIN + "\",\"password\":\"" + RANDOM_COMP_NAME + "\"}";
                HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                headers.set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, AUTH_TOKEN);
                HttpEntity<List> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(null, headers);

                HttpEntity<Object> applicationUser = postHttpEntity(LOGIN_REQUEST);
                ResponseEntity<String> response = template.postForEntity("/login", applicationUser, String.class);

                Assert.assertEquals(200, response.getStatusCode().value());

                List<String> token = response.getHeaders().get(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
                System.out.println("\n\n\n Token" + token);
                AUTH_TOKEN = token.get(0);
            }




            @Test
            public void test8ResetPassword() throws Exception {
                RESET_PASSWD_REQUEST= "{\"login\":\""+TESTINVITELOGIN+"\",\"password\":\""+TESTANSWER+"\"}";

                HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                headers.set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, AUTH_TOKEN);
                headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
                HttpEntity<Object> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(RESET_PASSWD_REQUEST, headers);

                // verify the forget password service with login id
                ResponseEntity<ApplicationUser> response = template.exchange("/resetpassword", HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity,
                        ApplicationUser.class);
                assertEquals(200, response.getStatusCode().value());
            }








            @Test
            public void testFindBranchWithId() throws Exception {
                HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                headers.set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, AUTH_TOKEN);
                HttpEntity<ApplicationUser> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(null, headers);

                ResponseEntity<List> response = template.exchange("/branches/" + TESTLOGIN, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity,
                        List.class);
                System.out.println("\n\n" + response);
                Assert.assertEquals(200, response.getStatusCode().value());
            }

            @Test
            public void testCanRegisterDetails() throws Exception {
                ResponseEntity<ApplicationUser> response = template.getForEntity("/registerdetails/" + EMAIL_TOKEN,
                        ApplicationUser.class);
                System.out.println(response);
                Assert.assertEquals(200, response.getStatusCode().value());

                response = template.getForEntity("/registerdetails/dOevI9", ApplicationUser.class);
                System.out.println(response);
                Assert.assertNotEquals(200, response.getStatusCode().value());
            }

            @Test
            public void testListOfQuestions() throws Exception {
                HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                headers.set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, AUTH_TOKEN);
                HttpEntity<ApplicationUser> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(null, headers);

                ResponseEntity<List> response = template.exchange("/questions", HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, List.class);

                System.out.println(response);
                Assert.assertEquals(200, response.getStatusCode().value());
            }

            @Test
            public void test9UserNRoles() throws Exception {
                HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                headers.set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, AUTH_TOKEN);
                HttpEntity<List> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(null, headers);

                ResponseEntity<ApplicationUser> response = template.exchange("/users/1", HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity,
                        ApplicationUser.class);

                System.out.println(response);
                Assert.assertEquals(200, response.getStatusCode().value());


                response = template.exchange("/users/"+TESTLOGIN, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, ApplicationUser.class);
                System.out.println(response);
                Assert.assertEquals(200, response.getStatusCode().value());

            }



            private HttpEntity<Object> postHttpEntity(Object body) {
                HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
                return new HttpEntity<Object>(body, headers);
            }

            @AfterClass
            public static void cleanUp() throws Exception {

                if (userfound != null) {
                    try {

                        Account account = userfound.getAccount();
                        UsersDetail userDetail = userfound.getUsersDetail();
                        Company company =account.getCompany();
                        UserQuestion question =userfound.getUserQuestion();
                        Collection<Branch> branchs = null;
                        if (company != null) {
                            branchs = branchRepository.findByCompanyId(company.getId());
                        }

                        System.out.println(" User before delete :" + userfound);
                        userRepository.delete(userfound);
                        userRepository.flush();
                        System.out.println(" User after delete :" + userfound);


                        /*
                         * accountRepository.delete(account);accountRepository.flush();
                         * companyRepository.delete(company);companyRepository.flush();
                         * userDetailsRepository.delete(userDetail);userDetailsRepository.flush();
                         * userQuestionRepository.delete(question);userQuestionRepository.flush();
                         * if(branchs!=null) for (Branch branch : branchs) {
                         * branchRepository.delete(branch); List<UserBranch> userBranchs =
                         * branch.getUserBranchList(); for (UserBranch userBranch : userBranchs) {
                         * userBranchRepository.delete(userBranch); } }
                         */

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("\n\n\n E :" + e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }

            protected <T> T mapFromJson(String json, Class<T> clazz)
                      throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

                      ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                      return objectMapper.readValue(json, clazz);
                   }

            @Mock
            private static UserRepository userRepository;
            @Mock
            private static UserDetailsRepository userDetailsRepository;
            @Mock
            private static AccountRepository accountRepository;
            @Mock
            private static CompanyRepository companyRepository;
            @Mock
            private static UserQuestionRepository userQuestionRepository;
            @Mock
            private static SecurityQuestionRepository securityQuestionRepository;
            @Mock
            private static RoleRepository roleRepository;
            @Mock
            private static BranchRepository branchRepository;
            @Mock
            private static UserBranchRepository userBranchRepository;

        }



error stack

 2019-01-02 19:41:50.350 DEBUG 1156 --- [    Test worker] c.e.spring.UserManagementUpdateTest      : Running with Spring Boot v2.0.5.RELEASE, Spring v5.0.9.RELEASE
    2019-01-02 19:41:50.351  INFO 1156 --- [    Test worker] c.e.spring.UserManagementUpdateTest      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
    2019-01-02 19:41:51.247  WARN 1156 --- [    Test worker] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
    2019-01-02 19:41:51.256 ERROR 1156 --- [    Test worker] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

    org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:139)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing dependencies. Try this dependencies block. Update jar versions as per your project.

```
dependencies {
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:*"
compile "org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.2.Final"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:*"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:*"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:*"
compile "mysql:mysql-connector-java:*"
compile "com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.5.5"
compile "org.projectlombok:lombok:*"
testCompile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:*"
testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:5.0.5.RELEASE"
compile "com.auth0:auth0-spring-security-api:1.1.0"
compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5"
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.5"
testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5"
}
```

Comment: we have replaced the exisitng dependencies with this one still getting the same error.

Comment: did you check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264118/spring-boot-test-fails-saying-unable-to-start-servletwebserverapplicationcontex

Comment: the problem is i have provided both build.gradle and pom.xml, with maven i m able to run the tests but gradle i m unable to run the tests and getting error, what might be the reason the tests r failing in gradle and not in maven

Comment: did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28273631/unable-to-run-junit-test-cases-after-converting-project-to-gradle-in-eclipse

Comment: had done all the steps mentioned still getting the same error.,